# How does MongoDB handle insert/update/delete merge conflicts in case concurrent distributed writes?

Tags: mongodb

How does Mongodb handle insert/update/delete merge conflicts in case concurrent distributed writes?

Inserts:

```js
op1: insert( { _id : 'joe', age : 30 } )
op2: insert( { _id : 'joe', age : 33 } )
```

Deletes:

```js
op1: set( { _id : 'joe', age : 40 } }
op2: delete( { _id : 'joe' } )
op3: set( { _id : 'joe', age : 33 } )
```

Updates:

```js
p1: update users set age=40 where _id='joe'
op2: update users set state='ca' where _id='joe'
```

Comment: objects with same _id will not be inserted !

Comment: When you're wondering about things like this, just try them out on a dummy collection in the shell.

Comment: hmm its about the concurrent writes; so I am not sure how I can test that

Comment: Neil you are rudest person I have ever met. Are you kind of a Admin of this webpage or u just happen to barge in all the conversations? I come from a free world I like to do things in my way and not get moderated each and single small things

Comment: These are atomic operations so the amount of time between them doesn't actually matter.  Pick an order and test it out.

Comment: Thanks Jhonny; I have scenario for example userA gets one DOC and meanwhile userB update sthe DOC and saves now when userA store it then it will change the DOC with userA changes? in that case it will overwrite the userB changes? so is it that last write wins? or some kind of merge resolution happens?

Comment: It all depends on how userA is updating the doc.  An [`update`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) can be written to either replace the existing doc or apply specific operations to the doc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> in case concurrent distributed writes

MongoDB doesn't support distributed writes. Writes [always go to the primary](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/#how-does-concurrency-affect-secondaries), so there can't be any conflicts, *theoretically*.

That isn't entirely true however - if you write to the primary just before it goes down, it's possible that the write is in the primary's journal but didn't make it to the secondary and your client code didn't get a response. In that (rare) case, you will have a conflict. MongoDB handles that by putting a [bson file in a special folder named `rollback`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-rollbacks/#rollbacks-during-replica-set-failover) when the server comes back up.

Apart from the intricacies of replica sets, operations are always performed in order (where, again for the replica sets, the order is determined by the primary's clock). As JohnnyHK already pointed out, updates can perform selective updates like `$inc` or `$set`, or replace the entire document. What makes sense depends on your application. If you perform a lot of `$inc`s, e.g. for a hit counter, the order doesn't matter, but it does, of course, when you perform a replace. In that case, following from the above, the last write wins. In general, I think one should put some though into object ownership, i.e. who is really allowed to replace a document.

If you want to have MVCC-like (multi-version concurrency control) behavior, e.g. allow different users to write to the same (logical) document with change tracking (something like git), you might want to check out [MongoMVCC](https://github.com/igd-geo/mongomvcc). That is only relevant if you want concurrency at the application level, so your users can deal with different versions/branches directly.

Comment: Thanks Christoph, that's exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for.